# Python Math Module Operators Precedence Incorrect?

Tags: python, math, operators, logarithm

I'm new in programming with python and searched this issue, thought there is an explanation, but couldn't find one.

Why this:
**`math.log(0.05/(2*0.000001),10)`**

> #output 4.3979400086720375

different than this:
**`math.log(0.05/2*0.000001,10)`**

> #output -7.602059991327962

Wasn't operators' precedence

> 1. `*`
> 2. `/`

> and it should give the same answer ?

Sorry if i'm missing something here.

Thank you for help!

Comment: withouth the (),  it's a left to right precedence.. so  ```0.05/2*...``` would evaluate the / first, then *.

Comment: It works exactly the same as it would in regular mathematics…?!

Comment: You can find the operator precedence here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence. `*` and `/` have the same precedence.

Comment: i though that the operators precedence will account for the parenthesis, thx everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`math.log(0.05/(2*0.000001),10)`this has OUTPUT
`4.3979400086720375` because you have use () in multiplied`2*0.000001` this. So as per basic rules of math for simplification i.e `BODMAS`
`Bracket of division multiplication addition subtraction`

The code has first multiplied the bracket`()`part and then it division take place.

Where as in the second `math.log(0.05/2*0.000001,10)` their is no use of `()` so it has first take division operation and then multiplied with `0.000001`

Answer (score 0):

So compiler performs operations like regular mathematics. These parentheses add a priority to an operation.
So, The first thing a compiler will do in these situations is to compute what is between parenthesis first so for the first line it will be computed this way :

math.log(0.05/**(2*0.000001)**, 10) ==> math.log(**0.05/(0.000002)**, 10) ==> **math.log(25000, 10)** ==> 4.3979400086720375

For the second it will be the first operation first as multiplication and division have the same priority order.
math.log(**0.05/2** * 0.000001,10) ==> math.log(**0.1*0.000001**, 10) ==> **math.log(0.0000001, 10)** ==> 7.602059991327962

I put in bold the operation that will be happening in each step.